# convert time interval since reference to time interval since 1970

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

i want know if it's possible convert this time interval:

```
TimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
```

to this time interval:

```
 TimeIntervalSince1970
```

without create a new NSDate, thanks!

Comment: what are you converting?  a NSDate or a NSTimeInterval?

Comment: i want convert NSTimeInterval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could calculate number of seconds between Jan 1, 1970 and Jan 1, 2001, and then just subtract it from your interval, but I don't see how's that any better than, say:

```
[[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:timeInterval] timeIntervalSince1970];
```